# Bias in lagged dependent variable

Tags: time-series, self-study, bias

$$
y_t = θy_{t−1} + u_t \\
t = 1,...,T; 
$$
I need to derive a formula for $y_t$ and show that 
$$
E\left[\frac{\Sigma y_{t-1}u_t}{ \Sigma(y_{t-1})^2}\right] \neq 0
$$

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your equations with the $\LaTeX$ markup features that the site supports. Please ensure it still says what you want it to. Also, you say you "need to derive", is this for a class assignment? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung I have the impression that this expected value is related to an OLS estimation of the model -and so, the term $\Sigma(y_{t-1})^2$ should be in the denominator.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, that may be. The original version of this Q had some meta comments about interpreting the (originally unformatted) equations, but nothing indicated that should have been a denominator. It would be nice if the OP could comment on this issue.

Comment: @gung Let's see.

Comment: yeah there shouldnt be a denominator. the question is, in my opinion, getting us to comment on the bias. the above variable is determined by a data generating process and i am estimating theta through ols. I just cant figure out how to get, using ols, that expectation and to show that it is not zero and hence that it is showing bias

Comment: You will find the answer here, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97508/ar-process-with-a-constant/97694#97694