Variance of the estimator of unconditional mean of AR(1) process
AR(1) process is defined as: $y_t=c+\phi y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is IID with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2<\infty$. For a stationary process, i.e. $\phi\ne 0$, the unconditional mean is $\mu\equiv E[y_t]=\frac {c}{1-\phi}$
It is usually estimated as $\hat\mu=\frac {\hat c}{1-\hat\phi}$. What is the sampling variance of this estimator?
If $\varepsilon_t\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ (also asymptotically for well behaving error distributions), we have estimators $\hat c,\hat\phi$ from bivariate normal. This is easy to see from OLS estimation of AR(1) coefficients. In that case, the distribution of this $\hat\mu$ must be Cauchy theoretically. Marsaglia has shown that in 2006. Even if we assume that the coefficients are from jointly t-distribution Press has shown in 1969 the distribution is still Cauchy.
So, how do we reconcile this theoretical consideration with the fact that the unconditional variance is finite $var[y_t]=\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}$?
Marsaglia (2006) offers that in practice we can truncate $-\infty<\phi$, then the distribution of the ratio of normals $\hat c/(1-\hat\phi)$ becomes normal. He posits that after observing that the sampling distribution is indeed almost indistinguishable from normal for some value ranges of $\hat c,\hat \phi$.
UPDATE:
I bootstrapped the distribution of $\hat\mu$ by repeated resampling model output residuals $\hat\varepsilon_t$ and re-estimating the coefficients, and the resulting distribution of $\hat\mu$ appears to be Gaussian.

In this paper, Hinkley, D. V. (1969). On the ratio of two correlated normal random variables. Biometrika, 56(3), 635-639,
the author attacks directly the distribution of the ratio of two correlated Normals with non-zero means, and he derives the density and the distribution function, which is a complicated expression involving the Normal and the bivariate Normal integral respectively. The expressions don't look like Cauchy.
He also shows that when the mean of the variable in the denominator is "sufficiently" higher than its own variance, the ratio approaches a Normal, and he derives approximation bounds.
My conjecture why this ratio maybe is not Cauchy,  is that likely, the Cauchy result depends on the denominator being zero-mean, and so concentrated at zero and so giving "often" very large values to the ratio, fattening the tails. When we don't have that and the denominator is concentrated "safely" away from zero, we avoid the Cauchy result.
But then again, the author does not discuss at all the existence of moments in the derived distribution.
So you may want to have a further look at that paper, since I only browsed it.
UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS
OP commented:

$c$ and $ϕ$ are normal that’s why μ is THEORETICALLY Cauchy. I’m
saying empirically this doesn’t hold. So there’s contradiction

Marsaglia 2006 writes at the beginning of Section 4:

As with the simpler Cauchy variate $x/y$, none of the moments of $T =(a+x)/(b+y)$ exist, in the sense that integrals are infinite. Yet
practical applications, in which the denominator $b + y$ is not
expected to approach zero, suggest that there may be some value in
assuming that the denominator $b + y$ is a normal variate conditioned
by, say, $−4 < y$.

So

the finiteness of the sample,
the approximation error in not having exactly the theoretical distribution (in real data or in simulated data),
some placement somewhat away from zero of the denominator, seem to be the drivers not only in computing empirical moments, but for these empirical moments to be meaningful.

All these say that we are saved by the fact that the data we have are not exactly distributed as the theory says in any case.

I think Hickley corrected his paper later see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334796

@Aksakal It is a correction regarding his comments on the Marsaglia 1965 paper. There is no mention in the correction that this affects the other results. But again, I haven't really worked through the paper.

But Alecos, I didn't understand the original question because  what does the distribution being cauchy have to do with the asymptotic variance of $y_t$ ? I don't know ? The variance of $y_t$ is obviously derived by assuming that $c$ is a constant. Thanks.

@mlofton The OP is not concerned with the variance of $y_t$ but with the variance of the estimator $\hat \mu$, musing that if $\hat \mu$ follows a Cauchy its variance does not exist.

@AlecosPapadopoulos the correction leads to a conclusion that the distribution is indeed Cauchy, it's explained also in Marsaglia's 2006 re-visit of the subject

@mlofton both the constant c and the AR(1) coefficient $\phi$ are random functions of the sample, thus the long run mean is the function of the sample. theoretically, it appears that the latter's distribution is Cauchy, which means that its variance cannot be obtained.

Thank you both for your answers. So, just to confirm,  you both are saying that, since the distribution of $c$ is cauchy, the model estimate for $c$, $\hat{c}$, has no consistent estimate because the variance of $c$  doesn't exist. Is that correct ? Thanks again.

@mlofton, no, c and $\phi$ are normal that’s why $\mu$ is THEORETICALLY Cauchy. I’m saying empirically this doesn’t hold. So there’s contradiction

Aksakal: Thanks. I have to go back and re-read everything from the beginning but atleast now I have all the pieces to understand it. One thing you way want to try is estimating the AR(1) model by minimizing the sum of the residuals squared using some BFGS type method. Maybe the results using OLS are not giving the correct results because OLS for the AR(1) is biased. ( that's shown in a thread on cross validated that I was never able to track down after seeing it once ) That's a total guess of course.

@mlofton https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97694/28746  and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/241063/28746

It will take me some time to go through the details but they look EXCELLENT at a glance. Thanks.
